# Copy 2D array into a middle of second bigger array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, mapping

Hello I'm struggling with copying an array into a middle of other bigger array. I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work even the indicies are correct. It's for https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/17. They ask for 3D array but I need to solve it with 2D array first.

I have an empty array like so

```
[
  [ '', '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', '', '', '', '' ]
]
```

and small array

```
[ 
  [ 'X', '#' ], 
  [ '#', 'X' ]
]
```

and my goal is to put the small array into a middle of the big empty one like so

```
[
  [ '', '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', 'X','#', '', ''],
  [ '', '', '#','X', '', ''],
  [ '', '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', '', '', '', '' ]
]
```

but I get

```
[
  [ '', '', '#', 'X', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', '#', 'X', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', '#', 'X', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', '#', 'X', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', '#', 'X', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', '#', 'X', '', '' ]
]
```

My code is

```js
let square = [ [ 'X', '#' ], [ '#', 'X' ] ]
let cycles = 2;
let startWidth = square.length;//square is the small array
let finalWidth = startWidth + (cycles * 2);//cycles is part of the task it tells
let twoD = new Array(finalWidth).fill(new Array(finalWidth).fill('')); how big is the bigger array/how many spaces from the edge to the small array

if(finalWidth % 2 == 0){//just made for even numbers once I make this work will edit it for odd too
        for(let row = (finalWidth / 2) - 1; row < (finalWidth / 2) + startWidth - 1; row++){
            for(let col = (finalWidth / 2) - 1; col < (finalWidth / 2) + startWidth - 1; col++){
                let i = col - (finalWidth / 2) + 1;
                let j = row - (finalWidth / 2) + 1;
                console.log(i, j, row, col)//logs correct indecies
                twoD[row][col] = square[i][j]
            }
        }
    }
```

Any idea is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Dude give a runnable snippet so we can reproduce

Comment: I can't see `cycles`  defined anywhere. Edit the code and make it runnable without errors.

Comment: @MaheerAli done all variables are now declared there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this logic:

- Create 2 variables:

  - `midRow`: To hold x position
  - `midCol`: to hold y position
- Then loop over provided value array.
- Use `midRow` and `midCol` to calculate the position to write.
- Override the value and print it

```js
const matrix = [
  [ '', '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', '', '', '', '' ]
]

const value = [ 
  [ 'X', '#' ], 
  [ '#', 'X' ]
]

const midRow = Math.floor((matrix.length - 1)/2)
const midCol = Math.floor((matrix[0].length - 1)/2)

for (let r = 0; r < value.length; r++) {
  for (let c = 0; c < value[0].length; c++) {
    matrix[r + midRow][c + midCol] = value[r][c]
  }
}

console.log(matrix.join('\n'))
```

---

I also see that your are using this to create the array:

```
let matrix = new Array(6).fill(new Array(6).fill(''));
```

Issue with `Array.fill` is that it creates value first and then push same value to all items. Usually it will not cause problem but since you are filling `Array`, you are copying reference of 1 array in 6 positions. Hence changing one will impact all

Hence your issue:

```js
let matrix = new Array(6).fill(new Array(6).fill(''));

matrix[2][2] = '#'

console.log(matrix.join('\n'))
```

Solution:

Use `Array.from()`. This creates dynamic array and you can fill as you want

```js
let matrix = Array.from(
  { length: 6},
  () => Array.from({length: 6}, () => '')
)

matrix[2][2] = '#'

console.log(matrix.join('\n'))
```

Comment: Thank you but what am I doing wrong in my code?

Comment: when I run my code then the console log logs - i, j, row, col = 
0 0 2 2
1 0 2 3
0 1 3 2
1 1 3 3
so
0,0 from square to 2,2 in big array and so on but it writes into the whole column why?

Comment: Instead of `Array.from` you can also you `fill()` and `map()`. `let matrix = Array(6).fill().map(x => Array(6).fill(''))`

Comment: @MaheerAli Just check your line and calculate the number if iterations and arrays that are created in it.

Comment: @MaheerAli thanks i like this 2d array inicialization better its shorter and doesnt have the object with length and I understand it more :)

Comment: and what should function that does this be called? copyToMiddle?
@MaheerAli

Comment: @DaliborTrampota Yeh its fine. copyToMiddle. I would have used `copyToCenter`.